# Natural way to use "same as" + relative clause

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm concerned my sentence may sound awkward

> In many cases we want to give the same set of directories as we give to `-L` to `-rpath`

when I want to say

> In many cases, if we want to give directories `A`, `B` and `C` to `-L`, we want to give `A`, `B` and `C` to `-rpath`, too.

especially because of the repeated "to" and the long object. How can I rewrite the above sentence for more clarity?

Comment: "In many cases we want to give the same set of directories to both -L and -rpath" sounds fine to me, as does "In many cases we want to give the same set of directories to -rpath that we gave to -L."

Comment: I find your example a bit of a [garden path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence), so it is a little confusing; but grammatically it's fine, and in speech (where you would indicate the structure by phrase intonation) it is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases where we *have given* directories A, B, and C to -L, we *will want to give* **them** to -rpath as well.

"will want to give" can be replaced with "must give" if you're referring to a *requirement* for things to work properly.